# Meteor Iron Router - Why does my app always goes to the base url on refresh or url load

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a meteor app that uses iron router. Every time I refresh the browser or input a url like `http://localhost:3000/gigs` my app refreshes back to the base url of just `http://localhost:3000`

Here is my router.js code

```
var requireLogin = function() {  
if (!Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {   
    Router.go('signIn');
    this.stop();  
}
};

Router.configure({ loadingTemplate: 'loading' });

Router.before(requireLogin, {only: ['tasks', 'gigs']});

Router.map(function() {
this.route('tasks', {
    path: '/', 
    waitOn: function() { return [ Meteor.subscribe('projects'), Meteor.subscribe('tasks') ] },
    layoutTemplate: 'twoColMenuLayout',
    template: 'tasksList',
    yieldTemplates: {l
        'taskDetail': {to: 'rightTemplate'}
    },
    data: {
        moduleName: 'projects'
    }
});

this.route('gigs', {
    path: '/gigs', 
    waitOn: function() { return [ Meteor.subscribe('gigs') ] },
    layoutTemplate: 'twoColMenuLayout',
    template: 'gigsList',
    yieldTemplates: {
        'gigDetail': {to: 'rightTemplate'}
    },
    data: {
        moduleName: 'gigs'
    }
});

this.route('gigSubmit', {
    path: '/gig-submit',
    layoutTemplate: 'oneColMenuLayout',
    template: 'gigSubmit',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'New Gig'
    }
});

this.route('signIn', { 
    path: '/signIn',
    layoutTemplate: 'blankLayout',
    template: 'signIn'
});
});
```

The strange thing is that if I change the 'tasks' path to be '/tasks' instead of '/' this problem doesn't occur and it works as I would expect it to. However when I do that I get a console error message that no '/' is defined. It doesn't seem to break anything but I hate having errors in the console.

I've also tried moving the 'tasks' map to the bottom in case it was matching first on this one and always going there, but that didn't make a difference.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I think layoutTemplate should only be in the .map() function.

Comment: The Iron Router documentation shows layoutTemplate can be used as it is in my example https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#using-a-layout-with-yields So I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this just recently. You'll want to order the routes from the deepest at the start to the most shallow at the bottom:

```
this.route('someDeepRoute', {
    path: '/deep/route', 
});

this.route('gigs', {
    path: '/gigs', 
});

this.route('gigSubmit', {
    path: '/gig-submit',
});

this.route('signIn', { 
    path: '/signIn',
});

this.route('tasks', {
    path: '/', 
});
```

Comment: I'm having this the same issue, ordering '/' at the bottom doesn't work for me.